# Override a gradle option defined in the master project

Tags: gradle

I'm adding an upload archive directory for all `subprojects` via

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
       flatDir {dirs '../REPO'}
    }
}
```

Now I need to specify a different directory for one subproject.

I've found out that doing it *adds* to the list, but I'd like to *replace* the directory. I know I could use `subprojects.findAll`, but I'll need the possibility to *override* a setting elsewhere, too.

**Disclaimer:** My question may sound stupid, but I'm using gradle since a few weeks and must confess, I know hardly anything about it. I like it and it works fine, but reading the manual is not an option (I'm just a BFU and I'd rather switch to makefile before reading it all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, the cleanest solution is to configure things the right way from the start. There are several ways to do this. For example:

rootProject/build.gradle:

```
configure(subprojects - project(":foo")) {
    uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            flatDir {dirs '../REPO'}
        }
    }
}

project(":foo") {
    uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            flatDir {dirs '../OTHER'}
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could have two auxiliary scripts `gradle/repoA.gradle` and `gradle/repoB.gradle`, and each subproject build script would apply the appropriate script with `apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/repoX.gradle"`.

Finally, overriding the value might work too (untested):

rootProject/subproject/build.gradle:

```
uploadArchives.repositories[0].dirs = ["../OTHER"]
```

PS: Now go and learn some Gradle. :-)

Comment: It works, and so does `uploadArchives.repositories.flatDir.dirs`, which I may understand one day. For now, I'm configuring this in the master, but this overriding is very handy and maybe cleaner. I've already spend some hours reading about Gradle, but what I'd need was sort of debugger which would show me the structure. Anyway, even without having any clue it works better than maven.